# OS freezes while using Blender (in edit mode)

Tags: modeling, interface, edit-mode, drivers

I am very new to Blender and ramping up my learning. But I am constantly facing a problem in Blender. Whenever I am modelling a cylinder (with just 8 vertices and mirror+subdivision surface+smoothed) the OS freezes I cant move the mouse at all. I am running Blender in my Dell Vostro 3350 with 6GB RAM along with AMD+intel Graphics. The OS I am using is Ubuntu 17.04. Please let me know your thoughts on how I can solve this.

Comment: check the settings of your subdivision surface - if the subdivisions in "view" are too high, your computer will run into these problems.
i would start with 1 and then increase whenever you really NEED it. 
Ps. the "render" subdivisions are the ones that will be calculated when you apply the modifier or render the scene

Comment: I thought so as well, but value of view for subdivision surface was always 1. Could it be that I am applying smooth and subdivision surface together?

Comment: it's a bit hard to tell, but generally it should be no problem to stack multiple modifiers (they always work on top of eachother)
maybe you can edit your question with a screenshot of your modifiers? or add your blender scene

Comment: I think I figured out , my hardware is just over minimum requirements. I think its just too much for it to handle. Its a 4 core processor with 6 GB RAM and integrated graphics not dedicated.

Comment: Funny you should mention that; I was just about to point out that GLSL rendering can occasionally do this when it needs the whole graphics card. However, I wasn't sure you were using that--but at 6 GB on a quad core, it might not matter. Start with a dedicated graphics card, and if that doesn't do it, up your RAM to a minimum of 8 GB; then you _should_ be fine.

Comment: Yeah sorry wasnt really sure before posting it :( anyways thank you very much for your advice :)